# Surprising int.ToString output

Tags: c#, tostring

I have been working on a project, and found an interesting problem:

```
2.ToString("TE"+"000"); // output = TE000
2.ToString("TR"+"000"); // output = TR002
```

I also have tried with several strings other than `"TE"` but all have the same correct output.

Out of curiosity, I am wondering how come this could have happened?

Comment: What I find odd is that the result isn't "T2+e000" - that's what I'd have expected, given the documentation. That would be using the `E` custom format specifier the odd part is that the preceding `T` seems to neutralize it.

Comment: Happens [also on Mono](http://ideone.com/ppJf08).

Comment: Lol, try also these two: `2.ToString("TR010")` ; `2.ToString("TR015")`.

Comment: "E" seems to look for a number of digits to allocate for the mantissa to the left of the E, so 2.ToString("T00E000") prints "T20E-001".  But when you do something like "TE000" it allocates 0 digits for the manissa. Strangely, `5.ToString("TE000")` prints "TE002".

Comment: @mikez On ideone it gives `"TE000"` :o

Comment: @BartoszKP I've tried it several places (including VS 2013, .NET 4.5) and I always get that result. See this for one: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W8BiNG

Comment: @mikez Not saying I don't believe you. Obviously this is some kind of a corner case. And your example is particularly good, because it supports this thesis, by exhibiting different behaviour on different compilers: http://ideone.com/BWFtqO

Comment: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUoZeW](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUoZeW) still seems to indicate this is the exponent it prints. It is just not clear if `2` should be `2.0E+000` or `0.020E+002` or `200.0E-002` etc. because we leave no hint on the mantissa.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yea it is like it is rounding the mantissa internally and 0.2 rounds to 0 but 0.5 rounds to 1. So 200.ToString("TE000") is "TE000" but 500.ToString("TE000") is "TE004".

Answer (score 1):

Simply based on Microsoft's documentation, [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]), your strings "TE000" and "TR000" are both custom format strings, but clearly they are parsed differently.

`2.ToString("TE000")` is just a bug in the formatter; it's going down a buggy path because of the unescaped "E". So it's unexpectedly assuming the whole thing is a literal.

`2.ToString("TR000")` is being interpreted as an implied "TR" literal plus 3 zero-filled digits for an integer value; therefore, you get "TR002".

If you truly want TE and TR verbatim, the expressions `2.ToString("\"TE\"000")` and `2.ToString("\"TR\"000")` will accomplish that for you by specifying TE and TR as explicit literals, instead of letting the formatter guess if they are valid format specifiers (and getting it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The ToString needs to PARSE the format string and understand what to do with it.
Let's take a look to the following examples:

```
2.ToString("TE000"); //output TE000
2.ToString("E000"); //output 2E+000
2.ToString("0TE000); //output 2TE000
2.ToString("T"); //throws exception
2.ToString("TT"); //output TT
```

This shows that if the ToString parser can understand at least part of the format, it will assume that the rest is just extra characters to print with it. If the format is invalid for the given number (like when you use a DateTime string format on a number), it will throw an exception. If it can not make sense of the format, it will return the format string itself as the result.

Comment: Wrong. `2.ToString("TE005")` prints `"TE005"`. So `"T"` is not a character to be printed before the "number". The number is ignored.

Comment: @BartoszKP What does `20000000.ToString("TE000")` give?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I'm not sure if you're seriously asking me to check it for you, or if it's some kind of an argument that contradicts my comment :) If the first, just use the Ideone linke I've given and see for yourself. If the latter, I don't follow - the number is also ignored in this case.

Comment: TE005 will print TE005 because the 5 in the end makes the whole thing meanins nothing. 0 or # has meaning. 5 no.

Comment: @Jauch Still, your explanation seems like just creating a random theory to match the facts. The part about "TR" is especially confusing, and adding date and time formats to this doesn't make any sense, since `Int32` explicitly uses numeric formatting.

Comment: @BartoszKP, if you try 2.ToString("T") you will throw an exception for using a "DateTime" format.

Comment: @Jauch Not sure how you're guessing "its" intentions, but it will just say the format is "invalid", not that it's "DateTime". Anyway, even if it did, that still proves that date time formatting is irrelevant here.

Comment: @BartoszKP, you're wrong. The "T" format is recognized by the function. If it wasn't, it would also give an error when using TT. But this is not the case.

Comment: @Jauch True, that's a good point. However, this is a nasty corner case (e.g. different `5.ToString("TE000")` result on different compilers) so judging the behaviour of `2.ToString("TE000")` from `2.ToString("T")`'s behaviour is too far fetched.

Comment: First it is decided if the format represents a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). The first type consists of a single alphabetic character optionally followed by one or more digits, like `"N"` or `"N2"`. If the string does not look like a standard format string, a custom format string is assumed. In standard formats, "any other single character" leads to an exception (see first link). In custom formats, other characters are just kept in the output.

Comment: (continued) This explains the easy cases `"T"` and `"TT"`. One is a (bad) standard format, the other is a (valid but useless) custom format. The examples from the original question were custom formats. I seriously doubt that format strings for `DateTime` are relevant when formatting *numeric* types (`int`, `decimal`, `float` etc.).

Comment: Format strings for DateTime are relevant to numeric types when they are identified as standard fotmat, because it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a numeric format to achieve a custom format, instead use something like this:

```
int i = 2;
String.Format("TE{0:X3}", i);
```

Comment: According to official documentation, you _can_ use a custom format for ToString() on numerics. That would be why there are two sections: 
Standard Numeric Format Strings and Customer Numeric Format Strings. But thanks for providing an alternate method.

Answer (score -1):

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). The `E` means the exponent part of the scientific notation of the number. Since `2` is `2E000` in exponential notation, that might explain it.

Comment: @GrantWinney What if you try `20000000.ToString("~E000")`? If you want the mantissa part shown also, maybe you have to include place holders for it in the format string? Edit: They do that in the examples in the section about [`E` specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierExponent).

Comment: @GrantWinney Why is it weird? What did you expect?

Comment: @BartoszKP Why would `TR000` be illegal? It is just a literal `TR` followed by the number expressed with three figures. The spec says that "all other characters" are simply copied to the result string unchanged.

Comment: @BartoszKP Now you try to mix "standard" and "custom" format strings, but that never happens. <strike>Since the format string has a length exceeding 1,</strike> "standard" formats are completely irrelevant here. Edit: Ignore the part I put in a "strike" tag.

Comment: Your example under the question seems convincing that the exponent explanation seems plausible. So I'll remove my comments.

Comment: As currently written this answer doesn't actually explain anything. Why should `2.ToString("E000")` return `"2E+000"` but the addition of the T lead to the loss of both the `2` and the `+`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I might expand my answer later. `"E000"` is not a part of the original question. While `"TE000"` is clearly a custom format, `"E000"` could be interpreted as a standard format. See my comment on the difference between standard and custom format strings under Jauch's answer.

Comment: So add this stuff to your answer not scattered round in comments then. As it currently stands your answer in isolation is not particularly informative.